# Unable to store the access token in angular constructor

Tags: node.js, api, token

I am able to get the access token but unable to use in a constructor method in angular service. console.log just prints the token but it is not getting assigned to a variable that I need to do.

Portion of my code.

```
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
        // get the access_token  via Node JS 
        this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/api/getToken').subscribe(d=>{
        this.token = JSON.stringify(d);
        console.log(this.token);
      })
    }
```

Comment: I am not able to  use this.token variable in the function where I am trying to pass it as bearer token to call the api to get the data

Comment: Does your node api working perfectly? Can you ensure it is not throwing any error? It would be helpful to debug if you share your node api code snippet.

Comment: @ShamsNahid yes the api works perfectly as I can see the access token printed in the console, but the variable does not contain the value outside constructor

Comment: `get` method is returning a Promise. Maybe you are trying to access the token before the promise being resolved. You should try to invoke the token after the api request being resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use the token in the constructor, make sure it is already received.

```
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
        this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/api/getToken').subscribe(d=>{
            this.token = JSON.stringify(d);
            console.log(this.token);
            // do your stuff
            // or invoke your method
      })
    }
```

Or if you want to perform some specific stuff with the token in another method `myMethod`, try this

```
        myMethod(private http: HttpClient) { 
            this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/api/getToken').subscribe(d=>{
                this.token = JSON.stringify(d);
                console.log(this.token);
                // some operation, involved with token
          })
        }
```

In this case, it is ensured that the token is retrieved and available before using it.